# format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am attempting to check and output the command line arguments given for a specific program "format.c" when called from the terminal. I am getting the following error and I do not understand what it is telling me.
error:
format specifies type 'char *' but the
      argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
here is my code thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int printArguments( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int i;
    printf( "Total number of arguments: %d", argc );
    for( i = 0; i <= argc; i++ ){
        printf( "argv[%d] = %s\n", i, *argv[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    if( argc != 3 ){
        puts( "You failed to enter the correct number of arguments." );
        printf( "You entered: \nargv[0] = %s\nargv[1] = %s\nargv[2] = %s\n",
               argv[0], argv[1], argv[2] );
        puts( "Argument format should be, \"./format (arg1 = int value)"
             "(arg2 = file name)\"\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    if( atoi(argv[1]) < 25 ){
        printf( "\nargv[1] = %d\nYou entered a value too small for the format\n",
        atoi(argv[1]) );
        return 0;
    }
    if( atoi(argv[1]) > 100 ){
        printf( "\nargv[1] = %d\nYou entered a value too large for the           format\n",
        atoi(argv[1]) );
        return 0;
    }

    printArguments( argc, **argv );

    return 0;
} /*end of main */
```

Comment: What about the warning is not clear afteryou have read the documentation of that function?

Comment: It is just below `enter code here`

Comment: I may have been in a bit of a rush to get my question out and did not explain myself very well. I am getting 2 warnings:                         format.c:30:33: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the
      argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
                printf( "argv[%d] = %s\n", i, *argv[i] );

Comment: format.c:65:24: warning: incompatible integer to pointer
      conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'char **'
      [-Wint-conversion]
        printArguments( argc, **argv );
                              ^~~~~~
format.c:23:38: note: passing argument to parameter 'argv' here
int printArguments( int argc, char **argv )

Comment: i do not have a great understanding of pointers and feel like this is the issue I have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int printArguments( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int i;
    printf( "Total number of arguments: %d", argc );
    for( i = 0; i <= argc; i++ ){
        printf( "argv[%d] = %s\n", i, *(argv+i) );
    }
    return 0;
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    if( argc != 3 ){
        puts( "You failed to enter the correct number of arguments." );
        printf( "You entered: \nargv[0] = %s\nargv[1] = %s\nargv[2] = %s\n",
               argv[0], argv[1], argv[2] );
        puts( "Argument format should be, \"./format (arg1 = int value)"
             "(arg2 = file name)\"\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    if( atoi(argv[1]) < 25 ){
        printf( "\nargv[1] = %d\nYou entered a value too small for the format\n",
        atoi(argv[1]) );
        return 0;
    }
    if( atoi(argv[1]) > 100 ){
        printf( "\nargv[1] = %d\nYou entered a value too large for the           format\n",
        atoi(argv[1]) );
        return 0;
    }

    printArguments( argc, argv );

    return 0;
} /*end of main */
```

Corrections are:
`printArguments( argc, argv );`
and
`printf( "argv[%d] = %s\n", i, *(argv+i) );`

[EDITED]
`printArguments` function expects arguments of type `int` and `char **`. That is what `argc` and `argv` already are. If you type `**argv`, you are dereferencing pointer twice. So, you are doing char ** => char * => char (this is what dereferencing does, "removes" one star).
So, function expects pointer to a pointer to a char, but it gets a char. Wrong.

Secondly, to explain the mistake with *argv[i], one has to understand how C programmer stores its data. Firstly, C program is given some internal memory that is divided in four segments: stack segment, data segment, heap segment and code segment. Data segments stores global variables, code segment stores program's code. Heap segment stores dynamically allocated variables. They do not have their names, and one retrieves data by it's address in memory. This is done with argv[i] i.e. *(argv+i). This is exactly the same thing, just another syntax.

So, let's overview how certain data structures are stored in memory:
  [image]
1. `int a[5]` is an array of 5 integers. If not global array, it is stored on stack. With this declaration, 20 Bytes are occupied in memory. We can save up to 5 integers in this array or less, but not more.
2. `int *p = NULL` is a pointer. It can point to an integer. With this initialization, it points nowhere. When we say that variable "points" at somewhere, we mean that it does not contain an exact data (number, character) but an address where this data is.
3. `int *p = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * 5)` is a variable that points at the first of five integers, i.e. it contains an address in the heap segment of the array of five integers. So, *p <=> *(p+0) <=> p[0]. You can visualize this by moving pointers around inside the array. So, p has the address of the first one. We retrieve others using some "pointers arithmetic".

[image] 
4. `int a[3][5]` is a statically allocated two dimensional array. It is an array which elements are also arrays. Since it is not dynamically allocated, it is stored on stack or data segment (depending on where it is declared, inside or outside of some function).
5. `int *a[5]` is an array of pointers. So, firstly there is a statically allocated array (stack/data segment). Afterwards, we can dynamically allocate member arrays (but they will be on heap).
6. `int **a` is a pointer to a pointer. So, `a` contains an address of a place that also has an address where some integer is stored. So, `a` points to a place that also points to a place with the integer.
After step b) we said it should point to first of the five integers in the array (of course, in heap).  What are members of this array? We said that `a` points to something that also points to something, so members are also pointers. We can say where these pointers point now. This is done after step c).

Finally,
[image] 
with chars we have the same situation as with integers.
7. is like case 1 (but you can see that we save one extra Byte for '\0')
8. is like case 5
Case with `char **` would be like case 6.

And the (*) case is how your `int argc` and `char **argv` look like. 
These are arguments to the `main()` function, and are therefore stored in the stack frame for it. `argv` is pointer that points to the first of the elements that are also pointers, pointing to fist character in arrays of characters[it would be wrong to say that `argv` is 'array of arrays of chars', that would be true if we had `char argv[50][50]`; it would be wrong to say that `argv` is an array of pointers, that would be `char *argv[50]`). So, `argv` is pointer that points to the first of n pointers that point to first chars.

So, finally, `argv[i] <=> *(argv+i)`  [this is how we retrieve ith pointer]
That means `*argv[i] <=> *(*(argv+i))` [this is how we retrieve where the ith pointer points at. It points at the first character of the ith argument!]

So, `argv[i]` is of type `char *`, and `*argv[i]` is of type `char`. You have tried to print argument with `%s` i.e. `printf()` expects "string" i.e. "array of chars" i.e. THE ADDRESS of the first char in a sequence of chars (which is what arrays in C actually store) and not just an actuall char.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: thank you, it compiles now. what was the difference between *( argv+i ) and *argv[i] ? i think that my issue is with pointers. i just don't understand how the syntax works and am bouncing around. I would like to find some information that gave me an understanding where I could read the syntax and just know what I am looking at. any guidance there would be appreciated. thanks again

Comment: Adding to what @Kale said: an answer is *far* better if it does not just provide "try this code" but also explains what was wrong.

Comment: @RadLexus that is pretty much obvious, but I am not able to provide explanation at the moment. I intend to provide the drawing with detailed explanation tomorrow morning, no worries ;)

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question. I am sorry for bad lighting on the photos and bad grammar, possibly. :) This is what I draw to my students. I am usually satisfied how they understand pointers. Hope it will be helpful to someone else, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing `argv[i]` not `*argv[i]` to `printf` in `printArguments`, as the type of `argv` is `char **`. So `argv[i]` is of type `char *` and `*argv[i]` is of type `char`. The `%s` specifier to `printf` expects a `char *` argument.

You should also be passing `argv` as the argument to `printArguments`, not `**argv` for the same reasons. You want to pass the entire list of arguments, not a pointer to the first character of the first argument. I'm surprised you're not getting a warning for that as well.

Comment: so if I am understanding you correctly, in your first sentence when I called the printf function I should have passed the "address", argv[i] and not dereferenced value it as *argv[i]? I think that my code in the printArguments function call when using **argv was basically passing the first element of the char array. Which would have been wrong, but I am on the right track?

Comment: Yes, I think you have the correct understanding. `printf` is expecting a `char *` argument due to the `%s` format specifier, and `argv` is of type `char **` ('pointer-to-pointer-to-char'). So, a single-level dereference of `argv` (either via pointer notation `*(argv+index)` or array notation `argv[index]`) yields the `char *` ('pointer-to-char') type that `printf` is expecting.

Passing `**argv` to `printArguments` is incorrect for the same reason - `printArguments` is expecting an argument of type `char **` but you are passing `char` since you dereference `argv` twice.

Comment: I would further suggest changing the prototype of `printArguments` to make `argv` a `const char **` or `const char * const *` if you want to ensure that none of the contents of `argv` are modified by the function (which I believe is the intent here).