# format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char

Tags: c

I am writing some code and I am very new to c. I need some help !!

I have tried changing some things around but because I'm new to this it hasn't really helped

```
int main()
{

  char name[10];
  int age;

  printf("what is your name");
  scanf("%s", &name);

  printf("what is your age");
  scanf("%d",&age);

  printf("%s",name);
  printf("%d",age)

}
```

> ```
> format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[10]' [-Wformat]
> ```

Comment: Try sscanf("%s", name);  or (char*)name

Comment: `scanf("%s", &name);` => `scanf("%s", name);`

Comment: Or even `scanf("%9s", name);` When you pass an array to a function, it decays to the pointer expected by `scanf`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [format specifies type 'char \*' but the argument has type 'char' \[-Wformat\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566317/format-specifies-type-char-but-the-argument-has-type-char-wformat)

Comment: "I tried changing things around" is not a very good debugging strategy.  Learn to read the error messages - they tell you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

replace

> ```
> scanf("%s", &name);
> ```

by

```
 scanf("%s", name);
```

or to also set the max size :

```
 scanf("%9s", name);
```

however warning if the input string is greater than 9 characters even only 9 are set in *name* (more the null character) the next characters are not discarded so `scanf("%d",&age);` will not work as expected

I encourage you to always check the value returned by *scanf*

Answer (score -1):

In the line `scanf("%s", &name);` you should remove the `&`. The argument for format `%s` is a pointer to the beginning of the string, which is `name`. What you are doing is passing a pointer **to a pointer** to the string.

Comment: The difference between an array and a pointer is well...none. Just that arrays have statically allocated memory while pointers don't.

Comment: They might look similar at the first glance, but they're different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer

Comment: @DarkAtom that is not true. An array is not the same as a pointer.

Comment: As I said, arrays are blocks of statically allocated memory. To access this block of memory you need a pointer to the beginning of it. The array name is basically a pointer to the beginning of the array.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, but the array name IS a pointer. Of course an array itself is not a pointer, actually it has nothing to do with pointers. It is just a block of memory. A pointer is a variable that holds (points to) an adress/location in memory.

Comment: @DarkAtom the array name is the whole object. It is not a pointer. A pointer only tells you about the first item to which it points, and nothing about the rest of it. Please read [Difference between pointer and array in C?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-pointer-array-c/)

Comment: @WeatherVane You are right. The array name holds information about the location of the first element (that is a pointer's job) AND about other information like the size of the array. Also the array name cannot be assigned any value (like a const pointer).